# i have to set all the database charset utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql

I am working in a multi language website  I have to set all table column charset `utf8_general_ci` in a database.

How can I change that. Is it a short method?

Answer (score 1):

Create a backup then execute following

For Database

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

For Table

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This :

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME,'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') AS    mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= "myschema"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```